# adding text to pictures js using jimp

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got a picture file that I want to add text in specified locations, I thought of using jimp, so I turned my `.ttf` into `.fnt` in order to use it with jimp and I get this error:

```
Error: no named row at line 1
    at splitLine (C:\\\node_modules\parse-bmfont-ascii\index.js:49:11)
    at parseBMFontAscii (C:\Users\\node_modules\parse-bmfont-ascii\index.js:18:20)
    at C:\Users\\node_modules\load-bmfont\index.js:39:18
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:511:3)
(node:11892) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11892) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I couldn't find any watermark module that have a font option as well, any advice on that?

Comment: I cleaned up the formatting in your question a bit. For error messages, you don't need to use StackOverflow snippets, just use a regular code block. You can create a code block by pasting your error into your question, selecting it and clicking on the `{}` button in the toolbar.

Comment: any solution till now?